# Make GameObject's Y Rotation be the same as the camera's

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, axes

I have a Cinemachine Freelook camera and i want it similar to Skyrim, where the character's rotation follows where the camera is pointing, but only on the Y axis so that i can move my mouse and look at the character from up and down;
[This video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fgz9m.jpg) demonstrates how MrKrabs can move in 3 dimensions, but won't turn.
I already tried creating a blank object and putting it at the center of the character, then using `transform.LookAt(Camera)` to make it point to where the camera is, and finally getting the Y value of the object's rotation, inverting it with `-transform.position.y` and applying it to MrKrabs, but it didn't work: it was jittery and overall just a bad user experience, is there a way to turn the gameobject based on the camera's rotation? (having the camera always watching his back)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick.

```
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles.y, 0);
```

Beware that if your camera is a child of your object it will rotate with it.